# add behavior to method with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Given `Sample.someMethod(...)` and `InvocationHandler decoration`, I want to create a dynamic subclass that overrides `someMethod` with

```java
someMethod(...) {
  decoration.invoke(...);
  super.someMethod(...);
}
```

My code looks like this:

```java
    Class<? extends Sample> dynamicSubclass = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(Sample.class)
        .method(ElementMatchers.named("someMethod"))
            .intercept(new Implementation.Compound(
                InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(decoration),
                SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE))
        .make()
        .load(Sample.class.getClassLoader())  // line 42
        .getLoaded();
```

...and it results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stack map frame
Exception Details:
  Location:
    pl/morgwai/sample/pojo/ByteBuddySample$Sample$ByteBuddy$PXUw8Sz7.someMethod(I)Ljava/lang/String; @27: aload_0
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 0a2a b200 0e04 bd00 1059 031b b800
    0000010: 1653 b900 1c04 00c0 001e b02a 1bb7 0020
    0000020: b0                                     

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2409)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$ForStaticField.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:122)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.LoadedTypeInitializer$Compound.onLoad(LoadedTypeInitializer.java:192)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:102)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6292)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6281)
    at pl.morgwai.sample.pojo.ByteBuddySample.main(ByteBuddySample.java:42)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
(I'm using byte-buddy 1.10.22 and openjdk-11)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to achieve

```java
someMethod(...) {
  decoration.invoke(...);
}
```

and

```java
someMethod(...) {
  super.someMethod(...);
}
```

by doing `.intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(decoration))` and `.intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)` respectively, so it seems, I'm not using `Implementation.Compound` properly...

**UPDATE-2:**

I'm also able to achieve

```java
someMethod(...) {
  super.someMethod(...);
  decoration.invoke(...);
}
```

by

```
.intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(decoration)))
```

but I can't do the other way around to achieve the order I need as `InvocationHandlerAdapter` does not implement `Implementation.Composable`...

Comment: it would be nice if whoever down-voted it and voted to close, explained exactly what needs to be clarified in the comment...  ;-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kindly [explained by Rafael Winterhalter](https://groups.google.com/g/byte-buddy/c/qDpzFwvKeAg/m/5lgmu6_xCQAJ) it's an unintended omission and in the next release `InvocationHandlerAdapter` **will** be implementing `Composable` ([commit](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/commit/0e225c91cb6d14ae544aba1aa67e1c3d32519b31) already pushed) and then the simplest way will be to do

```java
.intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(decoration).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE))
```